Issue with Calendar and Locale Prop in React Multi Date picker - Browser (non react-app)
I Have used the npmjs.com/package/react-multi-date-picker for range datepicker. I have created this for Browser(Non-react-app). But the calendar and locale props are not working in Browser app
ReactDOM.render(         React.createElement(DatePicker, {           calendar: {arabic_ar}                  }),         document.getElementById('datePicker')       );     });
this is throwing error like arabic_ar is not found
Please help me on how to use available calendar and locale props for browser app
